# Collision in dragable objects not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

My game has the ability to click and spawn objects and move them with the mouse. When the blocks collide with the walls however, I want them to be destroyed. I have set up the collision in the same way as I have on other objects but it doesn't seem to register. Below is the code for moving and the collision.

```
  void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if (prepPhase == true)
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        Vector2 objectPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        transform.position = objectPosition;
    }
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Collision");
    }
}
```

Everytime a new block is spawned it creates a clone of the previous object. Each clone comes with this script attached to it. I have also tested attaching the collision sctipt to the wall rather than the block, with the collision detecting the 'Block' tag. But still it doesn't destroy the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are essentially teleporting your object by setting the position.  This is preventing the onCollisionEnter2D event from firing.

You can confirm this by putting a log statement before the if

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2d Fired");
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Collision");
    }
}
```

Changing to  OnCollisionStay2D should do the trick.

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Collision");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! But for some reason still not with the Walls, but it does with other objects but I can sort that out; thank you!

Comment: It could be related to the size of the collider on the walls. Additionally, you may need to use RayCasting in certain situations to detect the collision.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Destroy` is not referencing to the exact game object in the collision. Instead, try:

```
Destroy(col.gameObject)
```

Read doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html

Comment: I have changed it to this and still no result. I have set it to write 'collision' to the log too and this does not appear. The 'Wall' tag is working everywhere else too.